# Sum of N independent standard normal variables

Tags: r

I wanted to simulate sum of N independent standard normal variables.

```
sums <- c(1:5000)

for (i in 1:5000) {
  sums[i] <- sum(rnorm(5000,0,1))
}
```

I tried to draw N=5000 standard normal and sum them. Repeat for 5000 simulation paths.

I would expect the expectation of sums be 0, and variance of sums be 5000.

```
> mean(sums)
[1] 0.4260789
> var(sums)
[1] 5032.494
```

The simulated expectation is too big. When I tried it again, I got 1.309206 for the mean.

Comment: Seems a reasonable result to me. The expectation is essentially 0 when you think that the variance is (asymptotically approaches) 5000.

Comment: Maybe you're right... But shouldn't the mean approach to zero as well?

Comment: I was expecting the mean would be much closer to zero than my simulated values, for example, 1.309 I got for one particular attempt.

Comment: The mean of the *standardized* random variable is `0.426/sqrt(5032.494)` in your case. That's 0 :-)

Comment: Note that sum of the independent normal variables is again normal. So `sum(rnorm(5000,0,1))` is equivalent to `rnorm(1,0,sqrt(5000))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ilir is correct, the value you get is essentially zero. 
If you look at the plot, you get values between -200 and 200. 0.42 is for all intents and purposes 0.

[image]

You can test this with `t.test`.

```
> t.test(sums, mu = 0)

    One Sample t-test

data:  sums
t = -1.1869, df = 4999, p-value = 0.2353
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.167856  0.778563
sample estimates:
mean of x 
-1.194646
```

There is no evidence that your mean values differs from zero (given the null hypothesis is true).

Answer (score 4):

This is just plain normal that the mean does not fall exactly on 0, because it is an empirical mean computed from "only" 5000 realizations of the random variable.

However, the distribution of your realizations contained in the `sums`vector should "look" Gaussian.

For example, when I try to plot the histogram and the qqplot obtained of 10000 realizations of the sum of 5000 gaussian laws (created in this way: `sums <- replicate(1e4,sum(rnorm(5000,0,1)))`), it looks normal, as you can see on the following figures:

```
hist(sums)
```

[image]

```
qqnorm(sums)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sum of the independent normals is again normal, with mean the sum of the means and the variance the sum of variance. So `sum(rnorm(5000,0,1))` is equivalent to `rnorm(1,0,sqrt(5000))`. The sample average of normals is again the normal variable. In your case you take a sample average of 5000 independent normal variables with zero mean and variance 5000. This is a normal variable with zero mean and unit variance, i.e. the standard normal.

So in your case `mean(sums)` is identical to `rnorm(1)`. So any value from interval `(-1.96,1.96)` will come up 95% of the time.